# ExtJS 6 app is crashing Cordova/iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, extjs

I'm testing an ExtJS 6 app on the latest version of iOS. I've tried three different versions of Cordova iOS platform (3.6, 3.8, and 3.9), along with two different versions of Cordova CLI (4.3, 5.1). For some reason, including certain stores or controllers in the requires section of app.js causes the app to completely crash, or to display a white screen. All of these components work just fine in the Android and web ports of our app. These problems are just happening on iOS.

Has anyone had something like this happen? It's really odd and we're unable to debug it as the Cordova webview won't allow output to the javascript console or use of the debugger when this happens.

Comment: Attach a remote debugger to the app running on your iOS (safari for example). You can use alert() to stop the execution allowing you time to attach the remote debugger to your webview.

Comment: Thanks for response...answer below...

Answer (score 0):

The problem wasn't the timing though in this case...I had plenty of time to attach a debugger, but once attached there was no console output.  We figured out the problem was related to us using Ext.device, which is obsolete. We replaced its functionality with the Cordova device plugin and the app is working again.